# Show that the linear map is surjective

Tags: functions, vectors

We have the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x_3 \\ x_1\end{pmatrix}$.

I have shown that this map is not injective, since the kernel doesn't contain only the zero vector.

Now I want to show that this map is surjective.

For that we want that for each $z\in \mathbb{R}^2$  there is vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}=z$.

So $z$ is in the form $\begin{pmatrix}x_3 \\ x_1\end{pmatrix}$. Therefore we already have the values $x_1$ and $x_3$ and we can arbitrarily choose $x_2$.

Is that corect toshow the surjectivity of $f$ ?

Comment: yes that is correct (and kind of trivial).

Comment: And is this  proof also complete as I did it? @ironX

Comment: this is both complete & correct.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @ironX